# How to refresh android Room database values in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, refresh, android-livedata, roomdb

I am developing an android application project in kotlin. I have room database values with coroutines.  After certain time (every 30 minutes), I want to refresh those android Room database, live data values.

Can anyone please help me on how to refresh android room database values?

Here, I have added Dao and View model codings, which I have used in my project. Hence, I want to refresh those values in every 30  minutes at Fragment.

```
@Dao
interface PeopleNearbyDao {

    @Query("Select * FROM people_nearby_table ORDER BY userID")
    fun getAllPeopleNearbyUsers(): Flow<List<PeopleNearByModelClass>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertPeopleNearbyUsers(peopleNearByModelClass: PeopleNearByModelClass)

    @Query("DELETE FROM people_nearby_table")
    suspend fun deleteAllUsers()

    @Query("DELETE FROM people_nearby_table WHERE userID = :userId")
    suspend fun deleteUser(userId: Int)

}
```

View model codings:

```
class PeopleNearbyViewModel(private val peopleNearbyRepository: PeopleNearbyRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    val allPeoples: LiveData<List<PeopleNearByModelClass>> =
        peopleNearbyRepository.allPeoples.asLiveData()

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insert(peopleNearByModelClass: PeopleNearByModelClass) = viewModelScope.launch {
        peopleNearbyRepository.insert(peopleNearByModelClass = peopleNearByModelClass)
    }

    fun delete() = viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d("PeopleNearbyViewModel", "delete() -->")
        peopleNearbyRepository.deleteAllPeoples()
    }

    fun remove(userId: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        peopleNearbyRepository.delete(id = userId)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use the work manager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=Cj0KCQjwpeaYBhDXARIsAEzItbFFe49Lc1Z2-DnJzB_V73LI3FaTrHMCJO2Kf4AAwFBFFn8aXuVdMrUaAsgxEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any example available to try for this one???

Comment: What do you mean by refresh exactly?

Comment: reloading live data values in current fragment. live data value sets in adapter. so i need to refresh live data values every 30 minutes